# how to show images after a short time in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, delay

i want to show images with delay after a button click

```
       final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do something after 5s = 5000ms

        }
    }, 26000);
```

i want to use this code for this
actualy,i want to show this images(on a motion layout)[image]

after 26s of clicking this button
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have your `Handler` and `postDelayed` method. Create the ImageView you want to show, default visibility as GONE or INVISIBLE and inside the `postDelayed` method, set it to VISIBLE.

Maybe I didn't understand your question correctly, but it seems that you already answered your own question.

Let me share some code. In your XML file, you'll have an ImageView and set the visibility property.

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/yourImage"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:visibility="gone" />
```

In your Activity, you'll first find and create a reference to the ImageView and then change its visibility property after the delay.

```
ImageView yourImage = findViewById(R.id.yourImage);

final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        yourImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}, 26000);
```

By default, your image will not show because it's set to GONE in the XML. The handler will execute the code inside the run method after 26s, then your image visibility property will be set to VISIBLE.

Comment: i Actualy dont know whats the code of changing image @Pedro

Comment: i never used handler code before,can you give me a code of changing a invisible imageView to visible after a delay?